# How to disable Save button in TinyMCE Editor when clicked on it? And how to put a scroller if TinyMCE Editor is in a div?

Tags: html, tinymce, editor

**First question.**
This is how my editor looks like:

```
        tinymce.init({
        selector: "div.Body",
        content_css : '/style/core.css',
        inline: true,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block: '',
        plugins: [
        "save advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "save insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",

        save_onsavecallback: function ()
        {              
            console.log("Sending body to database");
            var list = {};

            list.Id = "@Model.Id";
            list.Body = $("#PageBody").html();

            $.post("/home/SaveChanges", list, function (message) {
                $('#save').attr('disabled', true);
                $("#message").html("<strong>" + message + "</strong>");
            });

        }
    });
```

When I open the editor, the button Save is disabled because "save_enablewhendirty" is set to "true" in the plugin. If I start editing the text, the Save button enables. If I click on the Save button, it is still enabled, it becomes disabled only if I click once more somewhere in the editor. The problem is that I have to make the Save button disabled right after clicking on the button. Is that possible?

**Second question.**
The Editor is showing up in a div where the text for editing is located. And I have a problem - if I write too much text, I cannot scroll to see the text on the beginning because the div stays as it is, it doesn't depend on the text size. How can I put a scroller so I can see all the text even if I write a large paragraph?

**This is how the HTML looks like:**

```
      <div id="PageBody" contenteditable="true" class="Body">
  <span id="text1">@Model.Body</span></div>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
#Body, #PanelContent #PageBody {
border-top: 0.5em solid #009B7B;
padding: 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.5em;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,155,123,0.2)     0%,rgba(0,155,123,0.1) 50%,rgba(0,155,123,0) 100%);
position: relative;
width: 17.5em;
min-height: 100%;
margin-right: 1.25em;
margin-bottom: 1.25em;
clear: left;
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code that is called on save you can add a call to set the dirty status:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setDirty(false);
```

or

```
tinymce.editors[0].setDirty(false);
```

Comment: I put the function into the save_onsavecallback: function () { ...here... } but it is not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

As for your question on the DIV and scrolling - the default behavior for inline editing would be for the DIV to grow vertically.

- Are you using CSS to control the layout of the DIV?
- What HTML are you using to define the DIV?

A TinyMCE Fiddle or Codepen showing the issue would likely help people solve your problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the dirty flag doesn't work, trying calling the nodeChange function too.  This works for me:

```
    editor.setDirty(false)
    editor.nodeChanged()
```